# Using javascript to change CSS style in flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I am familiar with changing the CSS styles of a  using javascript, but I have a problem when the style is a flexbox style.

I have a div with id="foo" styles using CSS

```
#foo{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}
```

and I'm trying to change the justify-content:center to justify-content:flex-start using

```
document.getElementById('foo').style.justifyContent="flex-start";
```

but this does not aply the change to the div

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use camel case or the bracket notation. You can't throw a hyphen like that in the code.

```
document.getElementById('foo').style.justifyContent = 'flex-start'
```

OR:

```
document.getElementById('foo').style["justify-content"] = 'flex-start'
```

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen in the CSS property name gets treated like a minus sign in JavaScript and now you have attempts at subtraction on non-existent variables (i.e. `justify minus content`).

CSS property names that contain a dash, are typically converted to camel case when used in JavaScript, so `justify-content` becomes `justifyContent`.

You may also find it's easier to set up another CSS class ahead of time and then just use JavaScript to switch which class is being used with the [`classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead of coding inline styles.

Comment: Yes, I changed the .js to camelstyle and edited the question as it still does not apply the changes. Thanks